# JsonPath : check if the json matches

Tags: json, select, jsonpath

A simple question, however I cannot get it to work.

For this json document:

`{
  "firstName": "john",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 99,
}`

What would be the JSONPath query/filter expression to see if the **age < 100** ?

I tried `$[?(@.age<100)]` but that does not work.